# Is there a way to use rospy.info with complex messages?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I search about rospy.loginfo all I get is examples with topics that publish string messages.

What happen with complex messages? If I have

> def a_callback(msg):
> rospy.loginfo("The messages is ",msg)

and msg is a complex message, is there a way to make it work? or should I do something like

> rospy.loginfo("the message id is
> %d",msg.header.id)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370681/is-there-a-way-to-use-rospy.info-with-complex-messages?/) by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2021-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What happen with complex messages?

you'll see `The message is`  followed by whatever is the `__str__(..)`/`__repr__(..)` representation of the message.

In `rospy`, this will print the (almost) YAML formatted version of the message contents.

---

Edit: and just to clarify: `rospy.log*(..)` doesn't do anything special with your logstrings. So anything which is a `str`, or can be converted to a `str` can be passed to it.

That makes your question more about "can 'complex messages' be converted to a `str`" than a question about `rospy.log*(..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0